# Jest reference not found when running JS test using Chutzpah

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, chutzpah, gulp-jest

I want to integrate my Jest unit tests to TFS CI, so that during build it shows the Jest unit Test results in Build output of TFS. I used a extension Chutzpah. Below are references for it :
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/03/01/visual-studio-11-beta-unit-testing-plugins-list/

I followed https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt-harrington/2014/10/27/javascript-unit-testing-using-the-chutzpah-test-runner-in-visual-studio/ to set up chutzpah but my test are failing to discover Jest reference.

We are using Jest preprocessor as **Babel-preset-jest, babel-preset-es2015, babel-preset-es2015**. I tried adding those reference to test.js file. But still it failes with message **Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jest.**

Can someone help with exactly what references needs to be added for React js application to discover Jest unit tests in chutzpah. Or any reference to any react js application where such scenario is done.

Currently when executing Jest test using NPM Test it runs correctly, but I want it to be discovered in VS test explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Chutzpah doesn't support Jest. Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Running-JavaScript-tests-with-chutzpah) it currently only supports QUnit, Jasmine and Mocha.

I'm not familiar with Chutzpah but you'll need to implement a new [framework definition](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Chutzpah/FrameworkDefinitions) that will include Jest in the test execution environment.

Comment: This is correct. Support for Jest has not been added to Chutzpah yet.

Comment: Thanks Tim Reynolds and Matthew Manela. Can you please give any reference on how to add Framework defination for Jest. Or alternative plugin for TFS that does it already?